# Problem with update-initramfs and cryptsetup

Tags: 18.04, luks, initramfs, btrfs, cryptsetup

I am trying to update my initramfs but I get this error:

`cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab`

I am not really sure why this is happening because this is my fstab:

```
UUID=0a2cb47d-20dc-467e-9360-38a2e898379e   /boot   ext2    defaults    0   1
UUID=a97179ea-3a70-4ab8-b6e7-1b76a049dc0e   /   btrfs   defaults,subvol=root    0   1
UUID=a97179ea-3a70-4ab8-b6e7-1b76a049dc0e   /home   btrfs   defaults,subvol=home    0   2
UUID=a97179ea-3a70-4ab8-b6e7-1b76a049dc0e   /tmp    btrfs   defaults,subvol=tmp 0   2
UUID=189d2112-c85b-4bb9-8a91-682df21b52fe   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

and there is an entry for /.

For the background:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in a chroot environment. Furthermore, I have a btrfs file system and this is encrypted by using LUKS.

My crypttab:

`root UUID=1bc78817-271a-46b3-a51a-1b6013744a7c   none    luks`

My devives:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="189d2112-c85b-4bb9-8a91-682df21b52fe" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="80cd5dee-02"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="1bc78817-271a-46b3-a51a-1b6013744a7c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="80cd5dee-03"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="0a2cb47d-20dc-467e-9360-38a2e898379e" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="80cd5dee-01"
/dev/mapper/root: UUID="a97179ea-3a70-4ab8-b6e7-1b76a049dc0e" UUID_SUB="ed244bff-3e1a-4442-8426-9d478ad2ba35" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="80cd5dee" PTTYPE="dos"
```

My mounts:

```
/dev/mapper/root on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd_spread,space_cache,subvolid=520,subvol=/root_ubuntu)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=7721800k,nr_inodes=1930450,mode=755)
```

Hopefully anyone is able to help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So simple but overseen:

`apt-get install btrfs-tools`

in chroot.